# CAAnimationGroup play sound at beginTime of animation

Tags: ios, audio, timing, caanimation

I am try to play an sound at an specific time in an AnimationGroup how could i do this.

Should i use an NSTimer or an other Timer?

```
for (int i = 0; i<[bildr count];  i++) {
    ...
    CABasicAnimation *fadeInAnimation;

    if([[[bildr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"animation"] isEqualToString:@"fadeIn"])    {

        greenLeafImageView.alpha = 0.0;
        fadeInAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
        [fadeInAnimation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
        fadeInAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        fadeInAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        fadeInAnimation.duration = [[[bildr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"duration"] floatValue];
        fadeInAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + [[[bildr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"startTime"] floatValue];
    }else{
        // is sound -> time it
    }



    [animArray addObject:fadeInAnimation];
    [greenLeafImageView.layer addAnimation:fadeInAnimation forKey:nil];
    lastpic=i;
}

float totaltime=20.0;

CAAnimationGroup * group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
group.animations = animArray;
group.duration = totaltime;
[self.view.layer addAnimation:group forKey:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, yes, `NSTimer` is the path you have to take.

I wrote a class to coordinate sounds with animations. You may review it [here on github](https://github.com/michaelkamprath/iPhoneMK/tree/master/Views/MKSoundCoordinatedAnimationView). This class, `MKSoundCoordinatedAnimationLayer`, also allows you to "script" the animation through by passing a `NSDictionary` with the relevant image, position, alpha, sound, and timing information, which in turn allows you to configure/save the animation in a plist that you load at run time rather than having to modify code in order to tweak an animation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will try to use NSTimer like you did in your classes. Thank you.